# PHP: Reading text in a string within two characters

Tags: php, wordpress, inline

Hi so I'm still very new to PHP and am using a plugin on wordpress (to import CSV or excel sheets) that has an inline PHP function. I am trying to read an SKU number inside of an entire product description. The SKU number thankfully is within open and closed brackets "(" & ")". I am trying using substr and strpos but the problem I have with my inline code is that I just don't know how to set the closed bracket as end of the position. It just reads whatever is after the closed bracket because the logic behind strpos is (string,find,start).

So what adjustments am I clearly missing in this shortcode that I can use to adjust it to get it to work the way I want to.

`[substr({productdescription[1]},strpos({productdescription[1]},"("),strpos({productdescription[1]},")"))]`

This is how it would look using actual text which is what I'm using to test first

```
<?php
echo substr("please read the number (1212) text",strpos("please read the number (1212) text","("),strpos("please read the number (1212) text",")"));
?>
```

The plugin at least has a functions section I can write/use but I'd like to know if I can limit it to just using the inline PHP code instead.

Comment: When your string read `abc(123)cde`, the startposition of the SKU (the posisiton of the '(') is 4 (or 3 when it's 0 based), and the positiotn of the ')' is 8 (or 7 when its 0 based).  The **length** (third paremeter for `substr`) of the SKU is the end position minus the startposition plus 1 .

Comment: @all: sorry but now I know it's 0 based, because I tried: `$a='abc(123)cde'; print strpos($a,'(');` which returns 3.

Comment: which was why i used substr to retrieve the text but it's still incomplete

Comment: When you try: `$a='abc(123)cde'; print substr($a,strpos($a,'('),strpos($a,')')-strpos($a,'(')+1);` it will return `(123)`.

Comment: So, try: `$a='abc(123)cde'; print substr($a,strpos($a,'(')+1,strpos($a,')')-strpos($a,'(')-1);`, which should return `123`.

Comment: tested it and it worked! thanks a bunch LuuK it was down to the logic of it that i lacked

Comment: I hope that you learned something from the experience of asking on stackoverflow.... 

Comment: yes indeed hope if/when I return to ask again I would've at least had more work put into my fundamentals and thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading a substring between two characters can be done like this:

```php
$a='abc(123)cde'; 
print substr($a,strpos($a,'(')+1,strpos($a,')')-strpos($a,'(')-1);
```

This should find `123` which is between '(' and ')'.